# Selenium ip address changing code not working

Tags: selenium, proxy, ip

I am trying to make selenium change a ip address but it isn't working. The ip addresses are taken from https://sslproxies.org

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

const proxies = [
"47.243.167.134 :8889",
"154.236.179.233:1976",
"200.105.215.22:33630",
];

async function changeIP() {
 const proxy = proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxies.length)];
const capabilities = {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
  'args': [`--proxy-server=http://${proxy}`]
}
};

const driver = await new Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();

await driver.get("https://iplocation.com/");
}

changeIP();
```

Comment: not sure you can change IPs after creating the driver.  (that's set using the options object which sets how the browser is launched...)  You might be able to navigate chrome options using shadowDOM stuff, but that would be a pain.  Why not just use a proxy at the machine-level?  Have it set/change IPs?  (or maybe even router level?)  Selenium doesn't have to know about it at all.

Comment: Changing ip after creating the driver is only possible at machine or router-level. Or using a extension.

Answer (score 0):

Free proxies usually don't work or areextremely slow and unsecure.

For thet reason, you might consider using some cheap proxies.

Also, after changing the proxies, you need to restart the driver for an effect.